# Loading new data with Javascript/ajax based on server time and date

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I currently have a JS ajax script to load data from the Database, where the query is in load.php
How would I make auto load new content separately based on the server time and date?
Such as rather than having the whole DB table refresh every "5 Seconds"
But loading the current data once, then new data based on server time/date.
Here is my script>

```js
     <script language="JavaScript"> 
   window.onload = function() 
    { 
         $('#feed').empty(); 
         $('#feed').load("load.php"); 
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: You wouldn't need JavaScript to load new data in pages based on today's date.

Comment: How would I approach it?
I mean I was thinking of going the Ajax route, but then realised it would refresh "All the tables data"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot initiate sending AJAX data from the server without a request from the client (browser). So you should use the first request (the browser requesting the page itself) to calculate the time offset on the server (in PHP), and put your `.load()` function inside a `setTimeout` which will execute that many seconds later. So your PHP file would look something like this:

```
$time = 4300 // or whatever, based on your server clock.
echo '<script language="JavaScript">
      window.onload = function(){ 
         $("#feed").empty(); 

         /* if you want to execute it once at page load too:*/
         $("#feed").load("load.php"); 

         /* then load after $time milliseconds:*/
         setTimeout(function(){
             $("#feed").load("load.php");
         },'.$time.');
      }
      </script>';
```

Remember that `setTimeout`'s offset is supposed to be in milliseconds.

Websockets are another solution to your problem if you have full server access (like to sockets and stuff). They involve basically creating a websocket connection when the script is first executed, and then server and client can send messages to each other as they please. These messages can include the data you wish.

Comment: Thank you, refering to the server clock, How can I find out what mine is? It's an ubuntu server if that helps, and set to British GMT

Comment: PHP provides the localtime() and getdate() functions, which return server (local) time if set. _localtime_ provides a timestamp while _getdate_ provides an array. Ref: [getdate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getdate.php) & [localtime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.localtime.php)